# Why would an SPO webpart on a modern page only be functional for site admins?

Tags: permissions, sharepoint-online, spfx

I have created a simple (display only) SPFx webpart that makes calls into a list on the same site as it is used. Standard users have read access over this list, site owners have Full Control. When I add the part to a page, even site owners cannot see it. Site Members (& Owners) are able to see the page (published or not), but the content which should be displayed by the webpart is missing. Note that the basic html is visible, but the data which should be retrieved is not. If I elevate a site owner to a site admin permission level, the webpart then works as intended and data is retrieved correctly and displayed. Note also that other webparts on other pages served from the same library work correctly for all groups.

Does anyone have any suggestions to explain this behaviour?

I have tried: Rebuilding and publishing webparts, new test pages created by the same and other user accounts both published and unpublished. I've carefully changed permissions on the "Site pages" library, the "ClientSideAssets" library and the site scoped app library itself.

Answer (score 0):

I've answered my own question here. The error was caused by a REST query into the SPO list that contained a taxonomy (managed metadata) field. Expanding this field *appeared* to require the highest permission levels, thus all non admin users were unable to retrieve the data.

I later found an excellent article detailing the subject [here](https://threewill.com/pulling-managed-metadata-values-via-rest/).

I was able to trace this by serving through gulp into the online workbench, copying that URL into an incognito window for a different user account, and utilising the (Chrome) debugging tools. This tidy solution might potentially be of use to someone.